# Printing Exception type in Python using Errno

Tags: python, errno, try-except

I currently have code of the format

```
try:
    ....
except(HTTPError, URLError, socket.error) as e:
    print "error({0}):{1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
continue
```

But want to know which of the three triggered the exception.  Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Unnest the try/exept and catch them individually. Or use `isinstance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's important for you to *react differently* then you should catch them individually:

```
try:
    do_something()
except HTTPError:
    handle_HTTPError()
except URLError:
    handle_URLError()
except socket.error:
    handle socketerror()
```

But if you only mean that you want to display or log the error type along with its arguments, you should be using the `repr` of the error instead of trying to format it yourself. For example:

```
>>> try:
...     raise IOError(911, "Ouch!")
... except IOError as e:
...     print "error({0}):{1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
...     print repr(e)
...
error(911):Ouch!
IOError(911, 'Ouch!')
```

In terms of the information displayed, there's very little difference between the printed string you put together and just going with the `repr`. If you really want a "pretty" message to print or log, you can manipulate the string to your heart's content, but `type(e)` won't save you any effort, it's not intended for display/logging:

```
>>> type(e)
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `e.__class__.__name__`. It'll return values like `"ValueError"` or `"TypeError"`.

You could also just use `e.__class__`, which gives you values like `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>`

Answer (score 0):

```
def exception():
    try:
        //code that could raise a ValueError or TypeError
    except ValueError as e:
        print "ValueError"
    except TypeError as e:
        print "TypeError"
```

Just add more except blocks, each with code specific the a given exception.